# Disable device volume controls

Tags: android, media-player, volume

I created customized media player to play videos. i have volume button if click that button i just call device volume settings like this

```
 AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
 audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

in my media player settings if i set disable volume control i don't want to show volume even click device side volume up/down button.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can try overriding the volume key event

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN
            || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To help answer your intended outcome behaviour; 'i don't want to show volume even click device side volume up/down button'

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        switch( event.getKeyCode() ) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                // do something
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                // do something
                break;

            default:
                super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

will make it so that the volume does not get changed when you press down.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this Statement

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);
```

instead of

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```